# How to calculate Time offset and Day light saving(dst) in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having a web application which support multiple countries . I just want to show the time in my application according to user's country. I also want to change the time according to daylight saving time. Please suggest me some code in c#

Comment: Here sample from MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works:-

For converting the time to current timezone:-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

and

For checking DST:- 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642(v=vs.110).aspx